# How to scape from creating a FileStream everytime i want to save a file?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I have an application which i receive a stream every while to save it, so i want to create a global `**FileStream**` instead of creating every time i get a file. Is there anyway to do that? (Is there any alternative to FileStream) can do this?
because i already have a large object(LO) in my application which affected the the CLR performance.
P.S: the incoming streams would be saved in different files(different file name)
**UPDATE:**
I alreay create it in using phrase but the GC.Collect is affected by the LO created in my application

Comment: Don't do this. This would lock the file for other objects and if your stream gets into an invalid state you will have problems all over your code. The reason why you want to do this is quite fuzzy. Also, different files mean different streams. You could look into `File.WriteAllText` and `File.WriteAllBytes`. Although they work with `FileStreams` you will not have to bother

Comment: even if i called file.Close() ??

Comment: then your stream is closed for writing and has to be recreated, which means that you will have to create new streams nonetheless

Comment: I meant `lock the file for other programs`, not objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes`?

The `FileStream` object won't be very large in memory I don't think.  When it flushes, the content is written to file.

To avoid touching the large object heap, you could use a `List<byte[]>` and chunk the bytes into predefined sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If the streams need to be saved to different files i don't think there is a way of getting away from creating a new stream each time.

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind what you wrote: " the incoming streams would be saved in different files" I would strongly suggest to not do that. Just create a new FileStream for every file and close as soon as you finished, as fast as you can.

Regards.